# Could you explain why using tags {{ , }} in html?

Tags: html, css, jekyll, liquid

I want to use a jekyll theme on Github. So I cloned [this repository](https://jekyllthemes.io/theme/22990694/solid-jekyll), but it didn't include css files.

Some codes look like this:

```
<link href="{{ "/assets/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

What are these `{{` and `}}`?

These bring errors in my editor. The message is 'Tag start is not closed'.

I already try the following:

```
   <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I want to know why I have to write down like that.

Comment: you should read the jekyll docs, especially about templates: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These `{{` and `}}` are liquid syntax inside the HTML code. Liquid is a specific language used in Jekyll to make dynamic contents. You can see it as an alternative to PHP.

Here, your example `{{ "/assets/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}` means `insert the string "/assets/css/style.css" prepended with the value of site.baseurl (this variable should be declared in your _confil.yml)`.

But the double quotes in the expression conflict with the double quotes in the HTML code. Try:

```
<link href="{{ '/assets/css/style.css' | prepend: site.baseurl }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Once interpreted by the Jekyll engine, this may be generate the following HTML code:

```
<link href="http:/www.baseurl.of.mysite.com/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

An introduction to liquid [here](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/).

So you must run the jekyll engine on your cloned repository, using the appropriate command:

```
jekyll build
```

This will generate the HTML pages in `./_site`. Or:

```
jekyll serve
```

This will launch a test server, and activate auto regeneration of the HTML pages, making a preview available in your navigator at `http://localhost:4000/`.

More on jekyll commands [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).

I assume you first installed jekyll in your machine following [the documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/).

Once you are satisfied of the preview, push your repository on your github account. GitHub will run jekyll engine and generate the HTML pages in its server.

Given your username is "popcorn" on github, you can push your jekyll files either in:

- a repository called "popcorn.github.io": that's your user site, available at `https://popcorn.github.io/`.
- if you have an existing project "foo", push in this repository in a branch called "gh-pages" (this is the default branch for github pages; you may use an other branch, but you will have to mark it as github pages: see tutorial below): that's your project site, available at `https://popcorn.github.io/foo/`.

See [GitHub tutorial](https://pages.github.com/#tutorial).

Comment: I understand... so what should I do when I make blog by jekyll theme. couldn't I use jekyll theme repository on github  clone to my repo.

Comment: thanx! I already install jekyll and I input cmd jekyll build and jekyll serve. when I connect http://127.0.0.1:4000 and I can see it applied with theme. but isn't it local web sit. do i git on GitHub after build it

Comment: @Popcorn Yes, once you are satisfied with the preview, push your repository on GitHub. I edited my answer with more details

Comment: thanks your explaination.. here is my published github url https://vitalholic.github.io/master/ but nothing. just can connect like this https://vitalholic.github.io/master/index.html     but it isn't include css again.      what's wrong..?

Comment: i find different something, my project don't have gem  file.

Answer (score 1):

They are expansion points used by Jekyll to insert necessary values at build time. Consider them like C/C++ Preprocessor Macros. The reason you're getting those errors is this:

```
<link href="{{ '/assets/css/style.css' | prepend: site.baseurl }}"
      rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Use single quotes when put inside double quotes -->
```

Comment: do i build it using jekyll  eninge?

Comment: @Popcorn jekyll's engine parses them and outputs necessary data automatically, you don't need to do anything

Comment: I cloned other user's repository to my github. but my github pages not like that. here is my github pages url : https://vitalholic.github.io/vitalholic/

Comment: It didn't contain css on the pages.

Comment: @Popcorn have you tried copying the entire theme structure and using it?

Comment: I think it have to build with jekyll engine. I checked the web site after build with jekyll engine.  At first, I didn't build and uploading on Github.
thank you for your help.